# Remove a entry from app/etc/config.php

Tags: magento2.2

I've been working on a Magento 2.2 
and someone has run the "php bin/magento app:config:dump" command, 
so, according to this [documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/cloud/live/sens-data-over.html) , several backend configuration are locked (ie. the input are disabled).

The documentation says :

> In 2.2 and later, you cannot delete the config.php file to regenerate it. You can only edit the file to change or remove a value. This file includes more information than just configuration values.

So I assume that I can only delete the entry one by one..... I cannot find any piece of documentation about how to do it? Which is the command?